# How to write regular expression in php?

Tags: php, regex

I am very weak in regular expression. I need to check for this three strings 'name', 'fatherName', mohterName'. After checking I need to initialize these three strings with capital letter, like Name, FatherName, MotherName. And when It founds any capital letter in the string like fatherName it will add an white space before Name.

Can anyone please provide me the regular expressions for this problem. I am working wiht PHP.

Thanks.

Comment: `http://www.regular-expressions.info/` will get you started with regular expressions. Make an attempt to solve your problem and then others can help you if you get stuck somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code solves my problem.

```
$result = preg_match('*[A-Z]*', $name, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
            if(!empty($result)) {
            $name = substr_replace($name,' ', $matches[0][1], 0);
            }
            $name = ucfirst($name);
```

Thanks to everyone those are commented on my post.